# lisp: concat arbitrary number of lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In my ongoing quest to recreate lodash in lisp as a way of getting familiar with the language I am trying to write a `concat-list` function that takes an initial list and an arbitrary number of additional lists and concatenates them.

I'm sure that this is just a measure of getting familiar with lisp convention, but right now my loop is just returning the second list in the argument list, which makes sense since it is the first item of `other-lists`.

Here's my non-working code (edit: refactored):

```
(defun concat-list (input-list &rest other-lists)
    ;; takes an arbitrary number of lists and merges them
    (loop      
        for list in other-lists
        append list into input-list
        return input-list
    )    
)
```

Trying to run `(concat-list '(this is list one) '(this is list two) '(this is list three))` and have it return `(this is list one this is list two this is list three)`.

How can I spruce this up to return the final, merged list?

Comment: what does the cons operation do?

Comment: I assume we're getting socratic here. It takes two lists and returns a third that is the merge of those two, no? I recognize that I am `cons`ing and then basically doing nothing with the result, my question is how to use the loop to iteratively build up that result.

Comment: well, your title says concat. your code says merge, but you call cons. That are three different operations. what do you want to do?

Comment: I think they produce the same effect. `(concat-list '(some list) '(some other list) '(yet another list))` should produce `(some list some other list yet another list)`. I am using the `cons` operation to merge these three lists in order, or, concatenate them.

Comment: `(cons '(some list) '(some other list)) ; ==> ((some list) some other list)`

Comment: three different operations concatenate, cons and merge should do the same? unlikely. Btw., what you describe is called APPEND in Lisp. It's one of the basic functions.

Comment: Not quite what I'm saying; please read my whole answer. I'm looking to write something like `APPEND` from scratch to learn looping. If `CONS` is not the correct tool, and `APPEND` is, that's great -- how do I put that into my loop?

Comment: how about using the APPEND clause of LOOP?

Comment: Sure, my question is partly about correct syntax to do that. :)

Comment: How about (loop .... append list) ?

Comment: How about filling in the ellipsis? :) I updated my code above to include an attempt at that. Again, I'm brand-new to lisp, and trying to learn the syntax of loop.

Comment: look at your code...

Comment: you don't need a return clause. and you don't need to append into. See my example. (loop for list in some-lists append list)

Comment: That only returns the final two lists, merged, in my example code.

Comment: That's why I had the `into` clause, I recognize that I'm only looping through lists passed in through the &rest parameter otherwise.

Comment: (loop for list in (cons first-list more-lists) append list)

Comment: appending into something and returning is not needed, since append alone already causes the result to be returned. Check out some LOOP tutorials. There are several available.

Comment: That did it. Curious if there are alternate ways to do this without the `CONS`. Regardless, thank you for your time, Rainer Joswig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some pedagogical solutions to this problem

If you just want to *do* this, then use `append`, or `nconc` (destructive), which are the functions which do it.

If you want to learn *how* do to it, then learning about `loop` is not how to do that, assuming you want to learn Lisp:  `(loop for list in ... append list)` really teaches you nothing but how to write a crappy version of `append` using arguably the least-lispy part of CL (note I have nothing against `loop` & use it a lot, but if you want to learn *lisp*, learning `loop` is not how to do that).

Instead why not think about how you would write this if you did not have the tools to do it, in a Lispy way.

Well, here's how you might do that:

```
(defun append-lists (list &rest more-lists)
  (labels ((append-loop (this more results)
             (if (null this)
                 (if (null more)
                     (nreverse results)
                   (append-loop (first more) (rest more) results))
               (append-loop (rest this) more (cons (first this) results)))))
    (append-loop list more-lists '())))
```

There's a dirty trick here: I know that `results` is completely fresh so I am using `nreverse` to reverse it, which does so destructively.  Can we write `nreverse`?  Well, it's easy to write `reverse`, the non-destructive variant:

```
(defun reverse-nondestructively (list)
  (labels ((r-loop (tail reversed)
             (if (null tail)
                 reversed
               (r-loop (rest tail) (cons (first tail) reversed)))))
    (r-loop list '())))
```

And it turns out that a destructive reversing function is only a little harder:

```
(defun reverse-destructively (list)
  (labels ((rd-loop (tail reversed)
             (if (null tail)
                 reversed
               (let ((rtail (rest tail)))
                 (setf (rest tail) reversed)
                 (rd-loop rtail tail)))))
    (rd-loop list '())))
```

And you can check it works:

```
> (let ((l (make-list 1000 :initial-element 1)))
    (time (reverse-destructively l))
    (values))
Timing the evaluation of (reverse-destructively l)

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.000
Allocation   = 0 bytes
0 Page faults
```

---

### Why I think this is a good approach to learning Lisp

[This is a response to a couple of comments which I thought was worth adding to the answer: it is, of course, my opinion.]

I think that there are at least three different reasons for wanting to solve a particular problem in a particular language, and the approach you might want to take depends very much on what your reason is.

The first reason is because you want to get something done.  In that case you want first of all to find out if it has been done already: if you want to do *x* and the language a built-in mechanism for doing *x* then *use that*.  If *x* is more complicated but there is some standard or optional library which does it then *use that*.  If there's another language you could use easily which does *x* then *use that*.  Writing a program to solve the problem should be something you do only as a last resort.

The second reason is because you've fallen out of the end of the first reason, and you now find yourself needing to write a program.  In that case what you want to do is use all of the tools the language provides in the best way to solve the problem, bearing in mind things like maintainability, performance and so on.  In the case of CL, then if you have some problem which naturally involves looping, then, well, use `loop` if you want to.  It doesn't matter whether `loop` is 'not lispy' or 'impure' or 'hacky': just do what you need to do to get the job done and make the code maintainable.  If you want to print some list of objects, then by all means write `(format t "~&~{~A~^, ~}~%" things)`.

The third reason is because you want to learn the language.  Well, assuming you can program in some other language there are two approaches to doing this.

- the first is to say 'I know how to do this thing (write loops, say) in languages I know – how do I do it in Lisp?', and then iterate this for all the thing you already know how to do in some other language;
- the second is to say 'what is it that makes Lisp distinctive?' and try and understand those things.

These approaches result in very approaches to learning.  In particular I think the first approach is often terrible: if the language you know is, say, Fortran, then you'll end up writing Fortran dressed up as Lisp.  And, well, there are perfectly adequate Fortran compilers out there: why not use them?  Even worse, you might completely miss important aspects of the language and end up writing horrors like

```
(defun sum-list (l)
  (loop for i below (length l)
        summing (nth i l)))
```

And you will end up thinking that Lisp is slow and pointless and return to the ranks of the heathen where you will spread such vile calumnies until, come the great day, the golden Lisp horde sweeps it all away.  This has happened.

The second approach is to ask, well, what are the things that are *interesting* about Lisp?  If you can program already, I think this is a much better approach to the first, because learning the interesting and distinctive features of a language first will help you understand, as quickly as possible, whether its a language you might actually want to know.

Well, there will inevitably be argument about what the interesting & distinctive features of Lisp are, but here's a possible, partial, set.

- The language has a recursively-defined data structure (S expressions or sexprs) at its heart, which is used among other things to represent the source code of the language itself.  This representation of the source is extremely low-commitment: there's nothing in the syntax of the language which says 'here's a block' or 'this is a conditiona' or 'this is a loop'.  This low-commitment can make the language hard to read, but it has huge advantages.
- Recursive processes are therefore inherently important and the language is good at expressing them.  Some variants of the language take this to the extreme by noticing that iteration is simply a special case of recursion and have no iterative constructs at all (CL does not do this).
- There are symbols, which are used as names for things both in the language itself and in programs written in the language (some variants take this more seriously than others: CL takes it very seriously).
- There are macros.  This really follows from the source code of the language being represented as sexprs and this structure having a very low commitment to what it means.  Macros, in particular, are source-to-source transformations, with the source being represented as sexprs, written *in the language itself*: the macro language of Lisp is Lisp, without restriction.  Macros allow the language itself to be seamlessly extended: *solving problems in Lisp is done by designing a language in which the problem can be easily expressed and solved*.

The end result of this is, I think two things:

- recursion, in addition to and sometimes instead of iteration is an unusually important technique in Lisp;
- in Lisp, programming means building a programming language.

So, in the answer above I've tried to give you examples of how you might think about solving problems involving a recursive data structure recursively: by defining a local function (`append-loop`) which then recursively calls itself to process the lists.  As Rainer pointed out that's probably not a good way of solving this problem in Common Lisp as it tends to be hard to read and it also relies on the implementation to turn tail calls into iteration which is not garuanteed in CL.  But, if your aim is to learn to think the way Lisp wants you to think, I think it is useful: there's a difference between code you might want to write for production use, and code you might want to read and write for pedagogical purposes: this is pedagogical code.

Indeed, it's worth looking at the other half of how Lisp might want you to think to solve problems like this: by extending the language. Let's say that you were programming in 1960, in a flavour of Lisp which has no iterative constructs other than GO TO.  And let's say you wanted to process some list iteratively.  Well, you might write this (this is in CL, so it is not very like programming in an ancient Lisp would be: in CL `tagbody` establishes a lexical environment in the body of which you can have *tags* – symbols – and then `go` will go to those tags):

```
(defun print-list-elements (l)
  ;; print the elements of a list, in order, using GO
  (let* ((tail l)
         (current (first tail)))
    (tagbody
     next
     (if (null tail)
         (go done)
       (progn
         (print current)
         (setf tail (rest tail)
               current (first tail))
         (go next)))
     done)))
```

And now:

```
> (print-list-elements '(1 2 3))

1 
2 
3 
nil
```

Let's program like it's 1956!

So, well, let's say you don't like writing this sort of horror.  Instead you'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
(defun print-list-elements (l)
  ;; print the elements of a list, in order, using GO
 (do-list (e l)
   (print e)))
```

Now if you were using most other languages you need to spend several weeks mucking around with the compiler to do this.  But in Lisp you spend a few minutes writing this:

```
(defmacro do-list ((v l &optional (result-form nil)) &body forms)
  ;; Iterate over a list.  May be buggy.
  (let ((tailn (make-symbol "TAIL"))
        (nextn (make-symbol "NEXT"))
        (donen (make-symbol "DONE")))
    `(let* ((,tailn ,l)
            (,v (first ,tailn)))
       (tagbody
        ,nextn
        (if (null ,tailn)
            (go ,donen)
          (progn
            ,@forms
            (setf ,tailn (rest ,tailn)
                  ,v (first ,tailn))
            (go ,nextn)))
        ,donen
        ,result-form))))
```

And *now your language has an iteration construct which it previously did not have*.  (In real life this macro is called `dolist`).

And you can go further: given our `do-list` macro, let's see how we can collect things into a list:

```
(defun collect (thing)
  ;; global version: just signal an error
  (declare (ignorable thing))
  (error "not collecting"))

(defmacro collecting (&body forms)
  ;; Within the body of this macro, (collect x) will collect x into a
  ;; list, which is returned from the macro.
  (let ((resultn (make-symbol "RESULT"))
        (rtailn (make-symbol "RTAIL")))
    `(let ((,resultn '())
           (,rtailn nil))
       (flet ((collect (thing)
                (if ,rtailn
                    (setf (rest ,rtailn) (list thing)
                          ,rtailn (rest ,rtailn))
                  (setf ,resultn (list thing)
                        ,rtailn ,resultn))
                thing))
         ,@forms)
       ,resultn)))
```

And now we can write the original `append-lists` function entirely in terms of constructs we've invented:

```
(defun append-lists (list &rest more-lists)
  (collecting
    (do-list (e list) (collect e))
    (do-list (l more-lists)
      (do-list (e l)
        (collect e)))))
```

If that's not cool then nothing is.

In fact we can get even more carried away.  My original answer above used `labels` to do iteration As Rainer has pointed out, this is not safe in CL since CL does not mandate TCO.  I don't particularly care about that (I am happy to use only CL implementations which mandate TCO), but I *do* care about the problem that using `labels` this way is hard to read.  Well, you can, of course, hide this in a macro:

```
(defmacro looping ((&rest bindings) &body forms)
  ;; A sort-of special-purpose named-let.
  (multiple-value-bind (vars inits) 
      (loop for b in bindings
            for var = (typecase b
                         (symbol b)
                         (cons (car b))
                         (t (error "~A is hopeless" b)))
            for init = (etypecase b
                         (symbol nil)
                         (cons (unless (null (cddr b))
                                 (error "malformed binding ~A" b))
                               (second b))
                         (t
                          (error "~A is hopeless" b)))
            collect var into vars
            collect init into inits
            finally (return (values vars inits)))
    `(labels ((next ,vars
                ,@forms))
       (next ,@inits))))
```

And now:

```
(defun append-lists (list &rest more-lists)
  (collecting
    (looping ((tail list) (more more-lists))
      (if (null tail)
          (unless (null more)
            (next (first more) (rest more)))
        (progn
          (collect (first tail))
          (next (rest tail) more))))))
```

And, well, I just think it is astonishing that I get to use a programming language where you can do things like this.

Note that both `collecting` and `looping` are intentionally 'unhygenic': they introduce a binding (for `collect` and `next` respectively) which is visible to code in their bodies and which would shadow any other function definition of that name.  That's fine, in fact, since that's their purpose.

This kind of iteration-as-recursion is certainly cool to think about, and as I've said I think it really helps you to think about how the language can work, which is my purpose here.  Whether it leads to better code is a completely different question.  Indeed there is a famous quote by Guy Steele from [one of the 'lambda the ultimate ...' papers](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5753):

> procedure calls may be usefully thought of as GOTO statements which also pass parameters

And that's a lovely quote, except that it cuts both ways: procedure calls, in a language which optimizes tail calls, are pretty much GOTO, and you can do almost all the horrors with them that you can do with GOTO.  But GOTO is a problem, right?  Well, it turns out *so are procedure calls*, for most of the same reasons.

So, pragmatically, even in a language (or implementation) where procedure calls do have all these nice characteristics, you end up wanting constructs which can express iteration and *not* recursion rather than both.  So, for instance, [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) which, being a Scheme-family language, does mandate tail-call elimination, has a whole bunch of macros with names like `for` which do iteration.

And in Common Lisp, which does not mandate tail-call elimination but which does have GOTO, you also need to build macros to do iteration, in the spirit of my `do-list` above.  And, of course, a bunch of people then get hopelessly carried away and the end point is a macro called `loop`: `loop` didn't exist (in its current form) in the first version of CL, and it was common at that time to simply obtain a copy of it from somewhere, and make sure it got loaded into the image. In other words, `loop`, with all its vast complexity, is just a macro which you can define in a CL which does not have it already.

---

OK, sorry, this is too long.

Comment: "Instead why not think about how you would write this if you did not have the tools to do it, in a Lispy way." -- this is exactly the intuition that I'm looking to build. How should I build that? I wouldn't have thought to do it your way, but only because I wasn't aware of functions/macros like `labels` or `r-loop`.

Comment: this is a great answer by the way

Comment: if I were to implement portable list operations, I would use zero TCO-dependent code and LOOP all over the place. Additionally I find the LABELS using code harder to read and write. Though it's a step up from PROG and GO.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: well, sure, taste differs: yours, of course, is terrible while mine is wonderful (joke...).  You are right about requiring TCO: that makes me feel bad although it's a long time since I used an implementation (probably not since I stopped using Genera) which did not support it.  On a more serious note if I was actually writing this stuff  for production (and for some reason I could not just use `append`, I'd probably use `loop`: my point was really that if you want to learn *lisp* learning `loop` (or say, format-control strings) is not, I think, how I'd do it.

Comment: @lispquestions: I'll add an addendum to the answer trying to address your comment (and also Rainer's actually).

Comment: stopping to use Genera was the mistake! More seriously, the labels code looks like Scheme and does not translate that well to Lisp. It's also necessary  to understand why not to program generally on the tail recursion level, but how to use higher-level constructs like mapping, reducers, iteration macros, etc.. It's useful to understand it on a low level and also what the higher-level alternatives are - from a standpoint of using them, which is a different thing than implementing them. Giving the programmer a rich vocabulary on different levels...

Comment: @lispquestions: OK, there's now a (far too long) section at the end.

Comment: honestly, you should turn this into an (even longer) medium / blog post and get that puppy trending on hn

Comment: also it makes me think that if you REALLY want to learn lisp then the thing to do is to learn all of the methods available to you when you write a macro. are those listed out anywhere?

Comment: @lispquestions: I've added yet more at the end (but this will be the last bit) with another macro.  [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) is often thought of as a book on macros.  It is a long time since I read it however.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your function is a bit unfortunate, it becomes easier if you don't treat the first list specially.

The easy way:

```
(defun concat-lists (&rest lists)
  (apply #'concatenate 'list lists))
```

A bit more lower level, using `loop`:

```
(defun concat-lists (&rest lists)
  (loop :for list :in lists
        :append list))
```

Going lower, using `dolist`:

```
(defun concat-lists (&rest lists)
  (let ((result ()))
    (dolist (list lists (reverse result))
      (setf result (revappend list result)))))
```

Going even lower would maybe entail implementing `revappend` yourself.

Comment: Oups, fixed. (Padding to allow comment.)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually good style in Lisp not to use LABELS based iteration, since a) it's basically a go-to like low-level iteration style and it's not everywhere supported. For example the ABCL implementation of Common Lisp on the JVM does not support TCO last I looked. Lisp has wonderful iteration facilities, which make the iteration intention clear:

```
CL-USER 217 > (defun my-append (&rest lists &aux result)
                (dolist (list lists (nreverse result))
                  (dolist (item list)
                    (push item result))))
MY-APPEND

CL-USER 218 > (my-append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(loop for list in (cons '(1 2 3)
                        '((4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
      append list)
```